# Linq sort by element in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of People, and I need to sort this list  by their role and create a comma separated string with the first name of the people.

Lets say that the People class is:

```
public class Person
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

We have five different roles: Architects, Developer, Tester, BA and Designer.

The tricky part for me is that Architects need to be first in the group, followed by engineers and then the rest. How do we achieve this?

I tried using `var groups = people.GroupBy(i => i.Role);`. But I do not know how to sort on that. I would appreciate some help

**Update 1**

Thanks for everyone's help. First of all my sincere apologies. I had simplified my question a bit but I guess the way it was portrayed had changed the problem statement. There are 2 important things.

1. Role is not a enum , its a string.
2. There can be more Roles in the list its free-form textfield, but what we are only concerned about is Engineers and Architects. Rest of them can be in any order

Comment: What role or roles are the engineers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this is a simple way to do it:

```
var people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person() { FirstName = "A", Role = "Developer" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "B", Role = "Designer" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "C", Role = "Architect" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "D", Role = "Developer" },
};

int RolePriority(string role) =>
    role == "Architect" ? 0 : (role == "Developer" ? 1 : 2);

var ouput =
    from p in people
    group p.FirstName by p.Role into g
    orderby RolePriority(g.Key)
    select new
    {
        role = g.Key,
        names = String.Join(", ", g),
    };
```

This gives me:

[image: output]

You can set the order of the roles by modifying the `RolePriority` local function.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I guess my question was not portrayed correctly. I have updated it. Is it possible to have n number of roles, and only have to worry about architect and developer

Comment: @LibinJoseph - You did say "engineer" in your question. Can you clarify if it is just "Architect" and "Developer" that you need to order specially?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Make role a enum and order roles there for sorting:

```csharp
enum Role {
    Architect = 1,
    Engineer = 2,
    // the rest of them
}

var groups = people.OrderBy(i => i.Role); // I think this will work
var groups = people.OrderBy(i => (int)i.Role); // an alternative
```

2. (less pretty) Make a `Dictionary<string,int>` that will assign an integer value to roles. Then you can order by those values:

```csharp
var groups = people.OrderBy(i => roles[i.Role]);
```

Comment: But for your option to work role need to be type of "Role" enum right? . Mine is string

Comment: @LibinJoseph if you can't make an enum for some reason, dictionary approach will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

After clarity on the question, I updated my answer, which now answers the question and also is extendable that you can specify more roles on the `roleOrders` list to have priority over the rest of the roles.

```
var roleOrders = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "Developer", 2 },
    { "Architect", 1 },
    // You can add more roles here for priority ordering
};

var roleNames = people.GroupBy(p => p.Role, p => p.FirstName)
    .OrderBy(r => roleOrders.TryGetValue(r.Key, out var order) ? order : int.MaxValue)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => string.Join(", ", g));
```

Comment: Ths doesn't output what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use fluent API syntax of LINQ just like that:

```
var people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person() { FirstName = "A", Role = "Developer" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "B", Role = "Designer" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "C", Role = "Architect" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "D", Role = "Developer" },
};

// sort this list by their role and create a comma separated string with the first name of the people
var result = people
    .GroupBy(p => p.Role)
    .Select(g => new { Role = g.Key, Names = string.Join(",", g.Select(c => c.FirstName)) })
    .OrderBy(c => c.Role)
    .ToList();
```

[image]